# Deployment of plsql packages in oracle

Tags: oracle, deployment, plsql, package

I'm looking to learn about possible ways of deploying large number of plsql packages as dependencies seem to be quite a problem.
As it works now, packages are being deployed in several iterations redeploying em again if they couldn't be deployed in previous pass due to missing dependency.
I hope to hear about different approaches to the problem and will update my question if u happend to havequestions for me to make it more clear.

Would it even be ok to search guidance this way on SO?

Comment: What is a large number ? if you have "many" packages then you have to have some other "structure"-discipline in the codebase too like: these 25 packages belongs to a subsystem FOO and these 13 packages belongs to subsystem BAR, don't you ? Maybe you have different schemas for the subsystems too ? Is a package allowed to use any other package ? Do you implement separate public and private package APIs ? What other database objects are required (tables, object types, sequences, views) ?

Comment: Do you have source code in a version control system ?

Comment: @user272735 yes, several branches to cover all testing levels, also thousands of packages, tens of schemas, packages use other packages as there are common things, and all objects imaginable in oracle including ones you mentioned

Comment: You out-scale me so my practices won't help you. I'm very able to collect a list of changed scripts (PL/SQL code, alter table statements etc.) from version control system to a text file for each production deployment and execute those semi-automatically (sqlplus) without any dependency issues.

Comment: Can you briefly explain how did you resolve dependency issues via help of source control? We use svn.

Comment: It's nothing that scales. When we've tested the changes I simply check VCS logs (SVN) for changed files manually and collect the changed "scripts" to a master file that is executed manually. This is very possible and low-effort because the number of changes per deployment is low (at max about 20 changed database objects - packages, tables, views, objects). I also know the critical tables/views/packages and the major dependencies by heart so no problems to put then in the right order. After the deployment I check all invalid PL/SQL objects and re-compile them (I've scripts for that).

Comment: I have considered automation but because of the low number of changes I have concluded it just a waste of effort. During last 3 years (about 20 deployments) there has been only one human-error in the manual process (that was resolved in minutes). If I had bigger deployments I'd definitely check database migration tools like http://flywaydb.org/

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to install all specs first in proper order.
Then install all bodies.
All dependencies need to be predefined once in master install script.

Update:
What else you can do is:

1) load all package specs into main list (I assume all specs and bodies are stored separately. if not then it need to be done)

2) loop all specs from the main list.

3) try to compile it. Add to failed list if it fails.

4) When reach to the end of main list replace all items from it with items from failed list.

5) Go to step 2.

At the same time you can save results of the first run and second run could order items according to results of previous call. This will minimize number of iterations.

Bodies could be installed in any order...

However you need to keep in mind dependencies on the views and from the views - specs could depend on views (view_name%TYPE, cursors and etc) and views depends on package specs (could call package functions). This is not trivial problem... Can you explain how it is solved currently please?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That approach was observed, but there are thousands of packages, and they often change due to ongoing refactoring, so maintaining the master script requires too much time/effort.

Comment: Well that's result of bad design - you need to separate core packages for logging, dynamic sql execution, table management, error handling and other utilities. Next layer is low level business logic. Then high level business logic - wrappers for calls from outside Oracle, from other applications and etc. You can define it once automatically and then just maintain it. Even for thousand packages you do not change dependencies for all of them in each release.

Comment: Lots of things chanes over one day as its 100+ ppl working on it from renamim to rewriting, restructuring and so on.
Alot of it here could be improved, this question comes as part of the effort in improving it. Cant be done overnight and deadlines are deadlines.

Comment: Yes agree. And my comment came along with suggested approach. Let me updated my answer...

Comment: This is how it basically works now, try to deplay, and loop until its done, but some specs are using force method to be deployed regardless of its dependencies, which then invalidates all objects depending on this one.
And next deploy iteration will not redeploy those packages as they have been succesfully deployed and removed from the list.

Comment: What do you mean "force method"? May be you mixed up with views? Views can be compiled with force option. I personally don't like this option - it hides problems. I still think that you need try to get rid of any dependencies on views from your specs. In this case order will be 1)specs 2) views 3)bodies

Comment: `create or replace TYPE T_SOME_OBJECT_NAME FORCE is object`
note the force parameter

Comment: This is not a package - it's a TYPE (object). Generally speaking it is not recreatable object if there is any tables depend on it. If type_name exists and has type dependents, but not table dependents, FORCE forces the statement to replace the type. (If type_name has table dependents, the statement fails with or without FORCE.)

Comment: Generally speaking, I would also try to sort the procedural code according to its dependencies but with a large codbase recompiling whats left invalid seems to be the only way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I myself just install all the procedural code (in any order) and later (re)compile all invalid objects.

There are several way to recompile all invalid objects:

- [UTL_RECOMP](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/timesten.112/e21645/u_recomp.htm#TTPLP380)
- [DBMS_UTILITY.COMPILE_SCHEMA](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_util.htm#ARPLS73226)
- [Manually like Tom Kyte suggest and I use](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1418403973266)